# Rendering JavaScript & CSS files using Nginx in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, nginx, aws-fargate

I'm deploying an Angular application in a Docker container on AWS using ECS Fargate. The Angular application is being served up using nginx. I'm running into an issue where the application is routing all files back to the index.html file. This is preventing all the javascript & css files to load properly. Below is the `nginx.conf` that is being used in the container. Nginx is new territory for me, and I'm having some trouble getting the configuration file correct for the JS & CSS files. Initially, I was under the impression all files were rendering the `index.html` file because of the line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

I have changed that line to be `try_files $uri /index.html;` but am still having the JS files render back to `index.html`.

Any advice to get the other static files to render would be appreciated.

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  server {
    location /app {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
      include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
  }
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index /index.html;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $request_time';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    client_max_body_size 10m;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: This: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html` tells Nginx to first try to find the file that matches the URI as it is. If it isn't found, check if the URI is for a directory `$uri/`. If that isn't found either, then just serve the default index.html file. So Nginx is serving index.html because it can't find any of the other files. Where exactly are your .js and .css files in the Nginx container? Also you shoudl be able to test running this docker container locally to debug these issues before even attempting to deploy to AWS.